# Difference between get byte array from string in C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, arrays, string

I want to convert a string value to the same byte array in C# and Java with following codes:

**C#**:

```
string key="EA1302AFBCCF791CB0065BFAD948B092";
byte[] keyByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainKey);
```

**Java**:

```java
String key="EA1302AFBCCF791CB0065BFAD948B092";
byte[] keyByte = (key).getBytes("UTF-8");
```

But the length of the generated array is 32 in C# and 343 in Java. I have to create a byte array in C# same as Java, so please don't suggest changes for my Java code.

Comment: How did you check the lengths?

Comment: @ThomasTimbul I check it by test unit (break points) on netbeans 8.2 and Visual Studio 2019

Comment: (key) doesn't need to be in parenthesis :)

Comment: I highly doubt your reading is correct. Code seems ok. Regardless of the parentheses, it should work as expected. Couldn't reproduce at least.

Comment: @MahyarEsteki then I suggest you print `keyByte.length` to `System.out` instead, and you'll probably find that they match.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul I did that and the result is this: java => 343 and c# => 32

Comment: @MahyarEsteki Then show a little more code for context. Maybe write up a [mcve]. We must be missing something here.

Comment: The key is in hexadecimals. You need to decode them using a hex decoder (not present in the base install, but Bouncy Castle, among others, has one). It is called `Hex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String key="EA1302AFBCCF791CB0065BFAD948B092";
        byte[] keyByte = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Length: " + keyByte.length);

    }
```

output is:

```
Length: 32
```